# I can no longer install software using a list of items

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I can no longer install software using a list of items.

I've commented out git to see if it was the issue. It turns out nano will fail too.

My task:

```
- name: Install git, nano, curl, wget, unzip and mercurial
  apt: name={{item}} state=installed
  with_items:
#     - git
     - nano
     - curl
     - wget
     - unzip
     - mercurial
```

The error:

```
TASK [common : Install git, nano, curl, wget, unzip and mercurial] *************
failed: [local_vm] (item=[u'nano', u'curl', u'wget', u'unzip', u'mercurial']) => {"failed": true, "item": ["nano", "curl", "wget", "unzip", "mercurial"], "msg": "No package(s) matching '['nano'' available"}
```

A stab in the dark would be extra quotes perhaps?

From the console of my server:

```
me@server:~$ sudo apt-get install nano
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nano is already the newest version (2.5.3-2ubuntu2)
```

I'm running Ansible 2.2.0

**Update #1**

Python 2.7.6 on client, Python 2.7.12 on server.

**Update #2**

Either I got betrayed by the Windows Linux Subsystem or Ansible 2.2.0 is the issue. I tried on another VM (CentOS 7) where Ansible 2.3 is installed and the same script went through fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with items squashing for package modules.

If you can't update Ansible version, use `ANSIBLE_SQUASH_ACTIONS=[]` environment variables as a workaround.
It will increase execution time for `apt` module (because it will be executed for every item separately), but will not try to join items into single call.

Comment: It turns out I was able to upgrade to 2.4 via PPA. Works again.